# how to pass a php array to javascript array using jquery ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I followed other reslted question but still unable to solve this problem. I want to store the values of an array from ***php*** into an array of ***js***. I tried myself butr getting indefined value in all the cases i tried
Plese anyone let me know where i am wrong
my Php code

```
<?php
$var=5; 
$myArray = array();
while($var<10){
$myArray[]=$var;
$var++; 
}
echo json_encode($myArray);
?>
```

and the js code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery("#previous").click(function(){
var res = new Array(); var i= 0;
    jQuery.getJSON("phparray.php", function(data) {
while(i<5){
            res[i]=data.i;
         i++;
}
        });
    });
jQuery("#result").html(res[0]);
});
```

also treid this js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery("#previous").click(function(){
var res = new Array();
var i= 0;
    jQuery.getJSON("phparray.php", function(data) {
        jQuery(data).each(function(key, value) {
    res[i]=value;
          i++;
        });
    });
jQuery("#result").html(res[0]);
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP array to JS array with jQuery and json_encode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3250623/php-array-to-js-array-with-jquery-and-json-encode)

Comment: Search SO for 'php js array' and you will find many answers. The trick is not to try passing the array but to just echo the json array either into the javascript or somewhere else into the jQuery scope. Furthermore PHP has json encoding and decoding functions.

Comment: what is the value of $abc in php code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code

```
   <?php
        $var=5; 
        $myArray = array();
        while($var<10){
        $myArray[]=$var;
        $var++; 
        }
       $dataarray=array("myarray"=>$myArray);
        echo json_encode($dataarray);
        ?>
```

**Jquery**

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#previous").click(function(){
    var res = new Array(); 
        jQuery.getJSON("phparray.php", function(data) {
    var i= 0;
    while(i<data.myarray.length){
                res[i]=data.myarray[i];
             i++;
    }
  jQuery("#result").html(res[0]);
            });
        });

    });
```

Comment: it gives *data.myarray.length is undefined* and error at line 'while(i<data.myarray.length){'

Comment: Make sure there is no whitespace before echo json_encode($dataarray);
 in phparray.php. i had checked the code it is working fine for me.Made few changes Copy the latest code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is you are updating the result before the JSON has been loaded. There is also no reason to copy every item in the array in this case just set res = data (although the above example of sending back an associative array or JS object is good practice).

PHP

```
<?php
  for($var=5; $var<10; $var++){
    $myArray[]=$var;
  }
  echo json_encode($myArray);
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var res;
  $("#result").bind('update', function() {
    $("#result").html(res[0]);
  });
  $("#previous").click(function(){
    $.getJSON("phparray.php", function(data) {
      res = data;
      $("#result").trigger('update');
    });
  });
});
```