# Pass a php var to jQuery Function

Tags: php, variables, jquery

How do I pass a variable in a php file that is loaded into a page (DOM) to a jQuery function??

Iv'e tried various method's while searching online but I haven't figured out how to use them correctly.

I need the var navHeaderTitle to be passes to the jQuery load() callback function so it sets the HTML tag, #navHeaderTitle, to the variable called in the php file.

Thnx for you help.

php:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","user","pw");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("db", $con);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM some_list");

$navHeaderTitle = "MY NEW TITLE";//<--I NEED 2 INJECT THIS!!

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<div id='navItem' title='$navHeaderTitle'>";
echo "<h1>" . $row['label'] . "</h1>";
echo "<h2>" . $row['title'] . "</h2>";
echo "<p>" . $row['description'] . "</p>";
echo "</div>";
}
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

JavaScript in the HTML Head:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var navHeaderTitle = '';

    $(document).ready(  
        function() {
            $("#navContent").load('http://url/my_list.php', function() {
            $('#navHeaderTitle').text($(html).find('div#navItem').attr('title'));//<--GET THE VAR FROM LOADED PHP FILE!!
            }); 
        });
</script>
<body>
<div id="navPanel">

            <div id="navHeader">
                <img src="images/ic_return.png" style="float: left;"/>
                <img  id="listSortBtn" src="images/ic_list_sort.png" style="float: right;"/>
                <h4 id="navHeaderTitle"></h4>//THIS IS WHAT NEEDS THE VAR DATA!!
            </div>

            <div id="navScrollContainer" class="navContentPosition">
                <div id="navContent">HTML CONTENT from PHP GETS DUMPED IN HERE</div>
            </div>

        </div>
</body>
```

Ive tried using this but not sure how to:

```
$.get('scripts/my_list.php', {}, function(data){ 
                   data = split(':'); 
                })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace `echo("$navHeaderTitle");` with

```
echo("<script> var navHeaderTitle = $navHeaderTitle </script>");
```

and remove `var navHeaderTitle = '';` from the `<head>` script..

that will setup a JS variable like you're using, but you have to do that before the code in the `<head>` loads...

**EDIT**

ok don't `echo("$navHeaderTitle");` you can put it into the HTML like:

```
echo "<div id='navItem' title='$navHeaderTitle'>";
```

then in the JS you can do:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var navHeaderTitle = '';

    $(document).ready(  
        function() {
            $("#navContent").load('http://url/my_list.php', function(response) {
                $('#navHeaderTitle').text($(response).attr('title'));
            }); 
        });
</script>
```

here's a jsfiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JKirchartz/hdBzF/ (it's using fiddle's `/echo/html/` so the load has some extra stuff to emulate the ajax)

Comment: Thnx. I'm not there yet. I tried what you said but the data isn't loaded into the tag.  I'm not clear on what you said:  <...but you have to do that before the code in the head loads...> Could u epand please; I'm sure that's my problem.

Comment: @Andaero my first code is probably wrong for what you're doing, try my edit.

Comment: The PHP code is in the file at url/my_list.php - it echos HTML that is loaded into a DIV as per the load() function above.

Comment: I tried the your edit and still nothing. Please see my code edit.  Thnx

Comment: Thnx a bunch!!  Now I can go a long ways with that.

Answer (score 2):

I would have the php file return a json object that contains two parts, the html you want to echo and the title you want to use.

Then I would use jQuery's `.ajax()` function instead of `.load()` to get the return value from your php script in a javascript variable instead of dumping it directly as `.load()` does.

Comment: Thnx, this seem more logical to me. I'm search online to see how to do this. Could you post some code example in your answer to help me learn this.  Thnx again.

Comment: @Andaero I am not behind my computer right now, but here is an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397576/how-to-pass-a-php-array-to-javascript-array-using-jquery-ajax

Answer (score 1):

It would be cleaner to pass the var in a custom attribute (data-var), then fetch it width JQuery

```
$(some_element).attr("data-var");
```

I hate to mess my JS code with php.